# Someone does NOT want calender invites to show in calender unless they have been accepted. For Office 365 Outlook. Is there a way to turn off

Tags: office365

Not Accepted meeting (light blue slashes) Accepted solid blue line

When you have not accepted a meeting, there is a light blue dashed line to the left of the invitation

When you have accepted a meeting, there is a solid blue line to the left of the invitation.

This is difficult to see from your cell phone if you're looking at your calendar and you have 10 invitations for Monday afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either Accept or Decline the Invite.

Otherwise it will stay Pending. You cannot hide Pending invites, at least not in all the years I have used Outlook).

That is the way Outlook works.  (Outlook 365 and also reasonably recent prior versions).